# Changes to Variable Not Being Recorded After Loop?

Tags: java, variables, if-statement, reset

I am writing a simple set of programs (client and service) which calculate transactions for a bank account, ending with a summary of total withdrawals and deposits and the final balance. However, instead of keeping a running tab of the current account balance, the balance is resetting after each loop - so, for instance, if the first transaction is a deposit of $500, the current balance posted after that transaction will be accurate, but the in the next transaction (for instance, a withdrawal of $75), the current balance will not account for the previous deposit. Below are the module for the code computing the current balance, as well as the loop in which this module is called. This is my first time declaring variables in a constructor, so that may have something to do with the error.

```
public void computeCurrentBalance(){
   double deposit,withdrawal;

   if (choice == 'D' || choice == 'd'){
      System.out.print ("Enter amount of Deposit:   $");
      deposit = scan.nextDouble();
      currentBalance = initialBalance + deposit;
      totalDeposits = deposit + totalDeposits;
   }
   if (choice == 'W' || choice == 'w'){
         System.out.print ("Enter amount of Withdrawal:   $");
         withdrawal = scan.nextDouble(); 
         currentBalance = initialBalance - withdrawal;
         totalWithdrawals = withdrawal + totalWithdrawals;
   }
}
for (ctr = 0; ctr < 8; ctr++){
    accounts.enterChoice();
    accounts.computeCurrentBalance();
    currentBalance = accounts.getCurrentBalance();
    System.out.println ("Current Balance: $" + currentBalance);
}
```

Comment: this is just a useless code dump!

Comment: More consistent indenting would keep things clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

computeCurrentBalance() always sets `currentBalance = initialBalance + deposit` or `currentBalance = initialBalance - withdrawal` without anything changing `initialBalance`.  You need to change these statements to avoid the problem.